# How do i pass my list as parameter to the method?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to send my list as parameter to the function. I want to do something like this:

```
 public class SchoolClass
{
    private int index = 0;
    private string name = string.Empty;
    private List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

    public List<Student> Students
    {
        get { return students; }
        set { students = value; }
    }

    public void AddStudent(string name, int age)
    {
        Student newStudent = new Student();
        newStudent.Name = name;
        newStudent.Age = age;

        if (Students.Contains(newStudent))
        {
            Students.Add(newStudent);
            Console.WriteLine(newStudent.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public void RemoveStudent(int studentId)
    {
        Student foundStudent = Students.Where(x => x.Id == studentId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (foundStudent != null)
        {
            Students.Remove(foundStudent);
        }
    }

    public void CheckIfClassEampty(List<Student> students) <----here
    {

    }
```

Whats the best way to achive this?

Comment: Basically your `List<Student>` already have `Count` property; so, you need to check if `students.Count == 0`

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have? Or rather, what is the improvement you are looking for here?

Comment: u mean somthing like :   public void CheckIfClassEampty()
        {
            if (!students.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(students.ToString());
            }
        }
but i must pass the method the list first.am i right?

Comment: scroll down to the last function "CheckIfClassEampty". sorry for the big code. 
i want to know how to pass it the list so i can work on it.

Comment: you can not pass Properties as method parameters , instead pass backing variable. if i understood you correctly

Comment: @zipo_soft Yes, but I don't see any problem here. In fact `students` are already a member of your class, so  `CheckIfClassEampty` already has access to it, you don't need to pass students to the method. Remove the parameter from the method's header line and it will work.

Comment: What are you going to do in `CheckIfClassEampty()` method, you need count or whole list of students?

Answer (score 1):

As CheckIfClassEmpty is a part of the class you don't need to pass your list in as a parameter at all. You will have access to the internal field and the property e.g.

```
public bool CheckIfClassEmpty()
{
    // access Students or students directly
}
```

If you *want* to pass your list as a parameter then your method signature is correct, you just need to pass the data in e.g.

```
var school = new SchoolClass();
school.CheckIfClassEmpty(school.Students);
```

Comment: If you intend to use it this way I would make the method a static method.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood your question correctly then

you can not pass Properties as method parameters , instead pass backing variable.

Comment: yup , i think... my final goal is to see the names of students inside the class(room). some thing like:
 public void CheckIfClassEampty( the list of student )
        {
            if (!students.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(students.ToString());
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty hard to know what you are asking, but I suspect this will achieve what you want:-

```
public bool HasStudents()
{ 
    return students.Any();
}
```

I have changed the title of the method, as I think that HasStudents is probably a better name for what you are trying to achieve.